# how to get an item after mapping through an array

Tags: haskell

im trying to loop through my students array ( array of items of type Student) and then calculate the average of each student then get the maximum value between them  ,here is what i have tried but im getting the following error `Couldn't match expected type [Student]`:

**NB :** it would better if there is a way to get the name of the student who has the highest mark

```
data Student=
  Student{ name :: String
  , surename :: String
  , moy1 :: Double
  , coef1 :: Double
  , moy2 :: Double
  , coef2 :: Double
  , moy3 :: Double
  , coef3 :: Double
  } 

highestAverage :: [Student] -> Double
highestAverage students = maximum $ map  calculateAverage Student  students  

calculateAverage :: Student -> Double
calculateAverage (Student _ _ moy1 coef1 moy2 coef2 moy3 coef3) = ((moy1*coef1)+(moy2*coef2)+(moy3*coef3))/(coef1+coef2+coef3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing `Student` as second argument to `map` for some reason.

The `map` function takes only two arguments: a function to apply to every element of a list and the list itself. But you're trying to pass it three arguments: first argument `calculateAverage`, second argument `Student`, and third argument `students`.

I'm not exactly sure what you may have meant to achieve by that, but from the description of your goal it seems like you need to remove `Student`:

```
highestAverage students = maximum $ map calculateAverage students
```

Comment: Its works , would be great if i can show the name of the student instead of his average , i know that probably should be done on `calculateAverage ` method but i don't know how to do it , any help on that would be appreciated

Comment: Take a look at `Data.List.maximumBy` and `Data.Ord.comparing`.